# How to show countdown from timestamp?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, timer

I have to show countdown in my app,

i getting two timestamp
1. startTime
2. endTime

please help to show countdown timer.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CountdownTimer like this. It uses milliseconds, for example this uses 1 second interval(1000 milliseconds) as it counts down.

```
int input = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(mCount_Entry.getText())) * 1000;
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(input, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mDisplay.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mDisplay.setText("Countdown is over, boom*****");
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if it solves your problem, so others can learn from it. That's the very purpose of the site.